# limit universal reference to a single type using aliasing

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding, universal-reference

I have a member function of a class in which I'd like to use perfect forwarding for one of the parameters. However, the function being forwarded to only accepts a single argument of type `c2Type`, so I'd like the calling function also to only accept `c2Type` arguments, but obviously have to keep the universal reference to do the forwarding. It seems it can be accomplished using a default template parameter like so:

```
class c2Type 
{
    // some data members...
};

template<typename T, typename isC2Type = typename std::enable_if<
               std::is_same<c2Type, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value>::type>
    void configurationMessageHandler(T&& message)
{
    // some stuff...
   mapAddress(std::forward<c2Type>(message));   
}

mapAddress(c2Type&& message)
{
    // do stuff...
};
```

However, I need to check for this type on several member functions, and also such a long template seems unfriendly and unreadable. What I'd like to is create an alias for `isC2Type` like

```
template<typename T>
using isC2Type = typename std::enable_if<
           std::is_same<c2Type, typename std::decay<T>::type>::value>::type;
```

which I thought would make the `configurationMessageHandler` template look like

```
template<typename T, isC2Type<T>>
```

but that doesn't compile. How can I properly use aliases in this case?

Comment: You mean `template<typename T, typename = isC2Type<T>>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this can help you.

```
template<class U, class T, 
         class= std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, U>::value, T>>
using LimitTo = T;

template<class T>
void configurationMessageHandler(LimitTo<c2Type,T>&& message){
    // some stuff...
    mapAddress(std::forward<T>(message)); 
    //！！ Use T because the reference of c2Type maybe has cv-qualify
}
```

Even when there are many parameters, for example:

```
void foo(int); 
template<class A, class B, class C>
void foo(LimitTo<int,A>&& , LimitTo<float,B>&& , LimitTo<bool,C>&& );
template<class T>
void foo(LimitTo<string,T>&& );
```

However, there are some pitfalls with this trick:

1. Be careful that in some cases it won't work. This leads to fatal errors in some compilers. I don't know why.

   ```
     template<class...Args> 
     void foo(LimitTo<double,Args>&&... args){}
   ```
2. Use default parameters to avoid ambiguities, e.g. with regards to such constructors:

   ```
     template<class T>
     Ctor(LimitTo<string,T>&&,string* =nullptr) {} //string* or anything else

     template<class T>
     Ctor(LimitTo<double,T>&&, double* =nullptr) {}
   ```

Inherited constructors will cause some problems as default parameters can't be inherited. So change it to:

```
 template<class T>
 Ctor(LimitTo<string,T>&&,string*) {} 
 template<class T>
 Ctor(LimitTo<double,T>&&, double*) {}
```

Comment: This is a very clever idea. I think calling `Tself` something like `LimitTo` or `UniversalRef` with the order of the template parameters reversed would make it more readable.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus  yes，LimitTo or UniversalRef is also a good name.I thought that  Tself is means  T itself.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus I found that there is a potential error ,and we should use forward T instead of forwarding the real type